# Polymorphic type inference for by-name and by-value types

Tags: scala

I've been stuck with a type inference problem and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, there is a bug in the compiler, or it's a limitation on the language

I've created a dummy example to show the problem, the use case makes no sense, but trust me I have a valid use case for this

Let's say i have this code

```
val function: (Int, String) => String = (_, _) => ""

implicit class Function2Ops[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) {
   def printArgs(p1: P1, p2: P2): Unit = println(p1, p2)
}

function.printArgs(1, "foo")
```

That works and prints `(1,foo)`
Now, if I change the code to be (notice the by-name argument)

```
val function: (Int, => String) => String = (_, _) => ""

implicit class Function2Ops[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) {
   def printArgs(p1: P1, p2: P2): Unit = println(p1, p2)
}

function.printArgs(1, "foo")
```

It will print `(1,MyTest$$Lambda$131/192881625@61d47554)`

Now, at this point I could try to pattern match and/or use a TypeTag to extract the value in case is a by-name parameter, but, 
what I'm actually trying to achieve is to do something like this

```
trait Formatter[T] {
  def format: String
}

case class ReverseStringFormat(v: String) extends Formatter[String] {
  override def format: String = v.reverse
}

case class PlusFortyOneFormat(v: Int) extends Formatter[Int] {
  override def format: String = (v + 41).toString
}

implicit def noOpFormatter[T](v: T): Formatter[T] = new Formatter[T] {
  override def format: String = v.toString
}

val function: (Int, => String) => String = (_, _) => ""

implicit class Function2Ops[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) {
   def printArgs(p1: Formatter[P1], p2: Formatter[P2]): Unit = println( p1.format, p2.format)
}

function.printArgs(1, ReverseStringFormat("foo"))
```

Notice that the main intention is that I should be able to pass either the original type of the argument or a formatter instead, that's why the signature of this extension method uses `Formatter[TypeOfOriginalParam]` and that's also why I have `implicit def noOpFormatter[T](v: T): Formatter[T]` for when I don't want any formatting

Now, here, I can't do much as the code fails to compile with this error

```
Error:(22, 40) type mismatch;
   found   : ReverseStringFormat
   required: Formatter[=> String]
   function.printArgs(1, ReverseStringFormat("foo"))
```

I can make it run if I make the second type argument of my implicit class by-name

```
val function: (Int, => String) => String = (_, _) => ""

implicit class Function2Ops[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, => P2) => R) {
   def printArgs(p1: Formatter[P1], p2: Formatter[P2]): Unit = println( p1.format, p2.format)
}

function.printArgs(1, ReverseStringFormat("foo"))
```

this prints `(1,oof)`

Now, the main problem is that I want to do this for any function regardless if any of its arguments is by-value or by-name.
And that's where I'm stuck, I can create different implicit classes for every possible combination of cases where there is by-name params or not but it wouldn't be practical as I need to do this for every function from Function1 to Function10, and the the amount of possible combinations between by-name and by-value arguments would be massive.

Any ideas? Should I really need to care about the lazyness of an argument if I'm only interested in the type? Am I trying to do something unsupported by design or is maybe a bug in the compiler?

BTW, this is what I'm trying to avoid

```
val function: (Int, => String) => String     = (_, _) => ""
val function2: (Int, String) => String       = (_, _) => ""
val function3: (=> Int, String) => String    = (_, _) => ""
val function4: (=> Int, => String) => String = (_, _) => ""

implicit class Function2Ops[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, => P2) => R) {
  def printArgs(p1: Formatter[P1], p2: Formatter[P2]): Unit = println("f1", p1.format, p2.format)
}

implicit class Function2Opss[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) {
  def printArgs(p1: Formatter[P1], p2: Formatter[P2]): Unit = println("f2", p1.format, p2.format)
}

implicit class Function2Opsss[P1, P2, R](f: (=> P1, P2) => R) {
  def printArgs(p1: Formatter[P1], p2: Formatter[P2]): Unit = println("f3", p1.format, p2.format)
}

implicit class Function2Opssss[P1, P2, R](f: (=> P1, => P2) => R) {
  def printArgs(p1: Formatter[P1], p2: Formatter[P2]): Unit = println("f4", p1.format, p2.format)
}

function.printArgs(1, "foo")
function2.printArgs(1, ReverseStringFormat("foo"))
function3.printArgs(1, "foo")
function4.printArgs(PlusFortyOneFormat(1), "foo")
```

which it works (notice that I've used formatters or raw values randomly, it shouldn't matter if the original param was by-name or by-value)

```
(f1,1,foo)
(f2,1,oof)
(f3,1,foo)
(f4,42,foo)
```

but it seems super odd to have to write all of that to me

Comment: Really good question.

Comment: What about `val function: (Eval[Int], Eval[String]) => String` with [`Eval`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eval.html)?

Comment: The thing is I need to be able to do this with any function, I'm writing a library so I don't control what functions the user will provide, also most of the time they will be methods transformed into functions like `obj.method _` so I can't assume/impose anything about the shape/type of the parameters

Comment: Maybe extract part of the behavior into a type class? This way you will have 2 cases: by-value and by-name and you could take one type class instance for each parameter effectively handling all 4 combinations.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Sorry, I don't follow, how a type class would help me here? (maybe is because I'm thinking it on the context of the real problem, but if you could post a quick example it would help me a lot to understand your suggestion)

Comment: I wrote how I would handle this particular case, but I believe you can use the same approach to whatever case you need to handle.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok First of all, many thanks for your example! Sadly I realised that in my attempt of simplifying the question I ended up leaving out/making it not quite clear that the aim is to create a method in which each param is of another type that uses the original one as type parameter. I edited the question to reflect that and I think it makes much more sense now, I tried to apply your solution but as soon as I add the `Formatter` I end up in the same place as before

Comment: Can you explain this: "the main intention is that I should be able to pass either the original type of the argument or a formatter instead."

Answer (score 2):

I suggested using type classes and here is how I would implement them.

First I would create a type class for printing a single argument.

```
trait PrintArg[A] { def printArg(a: A): String }
```

Then I would implement instances for handling by-name and by-value parameter types:

```
object PrintArg extends PrintArgImplicits {
  def apply[A](implicit pa: PrintArg[A]): PrintArg[A] = pa
}
trait PrintArgImplicits extends PrintArgLowLevelImplicits {
  implicit def printByName[A] = new PrintArg[=> A] { def printArg(a: => A) = a.toString }
}
trait PrintArgLowLevelImplicits {
  implicit def printByValue[A] = new PrintArg[A] { def printArg(a: A) = a.toString }
}
```

Except Scala forbid us from declaring by-name type in other places than function declaration syntax.

```
error: no by-name parameter type allowed here
```

Which is why we're going to work around this: we'll declare by-name type in a function declaration and lift that function to our type class:

```
def instance[A](fun: A => String): PrintArg[A] = new PrintArg[A] { def printArg(a: A) = fun(a) }

def printByName[A] = {
  val fun: (=> A) => String = _.toString
  PrintArg.instance(fun)
}
def printByValue[A] = {
  val fun: A => String = _.toString
  PrintArg.instance(fun)
}
```

Now, lets put everything together:

```
trait PrintArg[A] { def printArg(a: A): String }
object PrintArg extends PrintArgImplicits {
  def apply[A](implicit pa: PrintArg[A]): PrintArg[A] = pa
  def instance[A](fun: A => String): PrintArg[A] = new PrintArg[A] { def printArg(a: A) = fun(a) }
}
trait PrintArgImplicits extends PrintArgLowLevelImplicits {
  implicit def printByName[A] = {
    val fun: (=> A) => String = _.toString
    PrintArg.instance(fun)
  }
}
trait PrintArgLowLevelImplicits {
  implicit def printByValue[A] = {
    val fun: A => String = _.toString
    PrintArg.instance(fun)
  }
}
```

Finally, we can use the type class in printer to handle all cases at once:

```
implicit class Function2Ops[P1: PrintArg, P2: PrintArg, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) {
  def printArgs(p1: P1, p2: P2): Unit =
    println(PrintArg[P1].printArg(p1), PrintArg[P2].printArg(p2))
}

val function1: (Int, String) => String = (_, _) => ""
val function2: (Int, => String) => String = (_, _) => ""

function1.printArgs(1, "x")
function2.printArgs(2, "y")
```

would print

```
(1,x)
(2,y)
```

Bonus 1: if you have a type which doesn't print anything useful if you `toString` it, you can just provide another implicit def/val and extend  support to all 3x3 cases.

Bonus 2: for this specific example I basically shown how to implement and use `Show` type class, so what you probably need to do *here* would be simply reuse existing implementations (and maybe provide implicit def for just by-name case). But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what your ultimate goal is, but I can explain to you why you're seeing what you're seeing.

There are two facts about the Scala language that combine to produce the problem you're in:

1. By-name `=> A` is not a type; and
2. By-name has to be part of a method signature because the calling code needs to construct a lazy value.

To see that (1) is true, observe that you cannot do this:

```
val a: => Int = 3
```

In other words, although `(=> Int) => Int` is a type, `=> Int` is not a type. You cannot have a value of type `=> Int`.

To see that (2) is true, consider what happens when you call a method with a by-name parameter:

```
def foo(a: => Unit) {
  println("1")
  a
}

foo(println("2"))
```

The calling code needs to know not to pass `()` as the argument, but rather to pass a promise. The calling code must therefore know that `foo` takes a by-name parameter, and so the fact that it is a by-name parameter must be a part of the method signature. Behind the scenes, the calling code must construct a no-arg method of type `() => Unit` and pass that.

Now, how do these combine to produce the problem in your code?

When you write:

```
implicit class Function2Ops[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) {
   def printArgs(p1: P1, p2: P2): Unit = println(p1, p2)
}
```

and pass an argument of type `(Int, => String) => String`, fact (2) requires that that `P2` cannot bind to `String`. If `P2` bound to `String`, then `f` would have type `(Int, String) => String`, which contradicts the rule that by-name-ness must be reflected in the method signature. Although your `printArgs` doesn't call `f`, it *could*, so the signature of `f` must preserve the by-name-ness.

However, fact (1) requires that `P2` cannot bind to `=> String`, because `=> String` is not a type. So, the only remaining option is for `P2` to bind to `() => String`. This is compatible with the implementation of by-name parameters as no-arg functions, and ensures that `printArgs` will receive the correct types from the caller and pass the correct types to `f`, should it choose to call `f`.

As a final comment, observe that it is not possible to abstract over by-name parameters because use of a by-name parameter must generate appropriate byte-code. Observe that the following two functions must generate different byte-code:

```
def foo(a: => Unit) {
  println(a)
}

def foo(a: Unit) {
  println(a)
}
```

Because type parameters in Scala are erased at compile time, it is never possible to use type parameters in a way that would alter a function's behavior. Therefore, it is not possible to abstract over by-name arguments using type parameters alone.

This final observation shows how, ultimately, you can solve your problem: You must abandon using pure type parameters and introduce value parameters. As Mateusz Kubuszok observes, one way to introduce value parameters is to use type-classes. There are other ways, such as type tags or explicit value parameters. However, in order to alter the behavior of a function, you must rely on something other than type parameters alone.