# Scala curried function to execute any expression on condition

Tags: scala, generics, currying

I'm trying to create a function that checks if a condition applies and runs any possible expression if it does, in case the condition doesn't apply this function returns a default value,
I'm able to do it in the following way:

```
def executeOnCondition[T](condition: Boolean, default: T)(f: => T): T = if (condition) f else default
```

however I'd like this function to be curried so that it first takes the condition and default and only later executes the expression.
imagined use:

```
val useLater = executeOnCondition(true, 3.14)
// do stuff
useLater { 3.14 * 2}
```

but when I try to create my curried function in the expected way:

```
def executeOnCondition[T](condition: Boolean, default: T) = (f: => T) => { if (condition) f else default }
```

I get this compilation error:

```
identifier expected but '=>' found.
```

I guess the problem is related to the use of generics,
can anyone shed some light and maybe offer a work-around?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper syntax:

```scala
def executeOnCondition[T](condition: Boolean, default: T): (=> T) => T =
  block => if (condition) block else default
```

For some reason *(bug?)* you can't type `=> T` as the type of a lambda input, even though the type is valid.

Comment: By-name as type parameter is theoretically forbidden but I was able to work around it, see my answer in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043365/polymorphic-type-inference-for-by-name-and-by-value-types/52093685#52093685).

Comment: amazing, thanks!